# Cannot add any file to GIT "libgit2 returned: Invalid data in index - invalid entry"

Tags: c++, git, boost

Cannot add any new file to GIT repo.

```
libgit2 returned: Invalid data in index - invalid entry
```

Have recently locally committed changes to an existing Boost.Math sub-module (commit OK).

(But realized that I had forgotten to add a few new files, so tried to add and recommit, but failed at the add stage).

`git status` shows expected untracked files and ends:

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

```
I:\modular-boost\libs\math>
```

.gitignore is the standard modular-boost issue and looks OK.

```
I:\modular-boost\libs\math>git version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried what the message suggests? _(use "git add" to track)_. Otherwise, why don't you start by listing the untracked paths and the gitignore..

Answer (score 2):

Error suggests corrupt index. Its easier to re-clone the repo else where and re-apply the changes. The other painful approach would be to hand edit the corrupt index. `git ls-files` would show you the files in the current index.

Answer (score 1):

The version 2.4.0.2 of TortoiseGit has fixed this issus, please download the newest version.

Comment: As this question is more than two years old, the asker has probably resolved this. In any case, thank you for leaving a note to any other person who might have this issue and welcome to StackOverflow. **Also**, if there is something you can reference from the documentation about a bugfix, that's always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I had the same error with `git version 2.19.1.windows.1`

The issue went away forcing the index to rebuild from scratch.

```
mv .git/index .git/index_old
git reset
```

Comment: This solution has worked for me 

Answer (score 0):

Had this same error with TortoiseGit and windows explorer. Re-installing TortoiseGit resolved the error.